# Cast java types to scala TypeTags

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I encountered the following method:

```
def register(name: String, func: Function0[RT], RT: TypeTag): UserDefinedFunction = { ...}
```

I'm calling this from inside a java method.

How can I cast the primitive types of java to TypeTags in Scala?

Comment: That signature doesn't make sense. What is `RT`? Where is the type parameter for `TypeTag`?

Comment: Could be Spark UDF registration.. register(String name, scala.Function0<RT> func, scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag<RT> evidence$1) but there's probably a Java API alternative for that, taking a lambda and a DataType? Which Spark version?

Comment: This is spark udf config for UDFs with zero parameters. Currently it is not supported for Java. I'm trying to extend and use the scala traits.  But i cant cast java types to scala TypeTags. Is there anyway of doing that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589179/how-to-get-scalas-typetag-and-classtag-in-java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037901/how-to-get-the-typetag-for-a-class-in-java