# TypeTag inference when overriding a scala method from Java

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

Given the following scala base classes:

```
trait P2pRpc {

  import reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

  def request[U: TypeTag, V: TypeTag](req: P2pReq[U]): P2pResp[V]

}
```

Where the P2p classes are:

```
abstract class P2pMessage[T] extends _root_.java.io.Serializable {
  def value(): T
}

abstract class P2pReq[T] extends P2pMessage[T] with _root_.java.io.Serializable


abstract class P2pReq[T] extends P2pMessage[T] with _root_.java.io.Serializable
```

And given the following simple java classes:

```
  public static class ExecuteAppCommandReq extends P2pReq<String> {
    public String value;

    public ExecuteAppCommandReq(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  public static class ExecuteAppCommandResp extends P2pResp<String> {
    public String value;

    public ExecuteAppCommandResp(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
```

The following is an attempt to override the `P2pRpc.request()` method from java:

```
 public ExecuteAppCommandResp executeAppCommand(ExecuteAppCommandReq req) {
    return (ExecuteAppCommandResp) getRpc().request(req);
  }
```

But that is not working:

```
Error:(19, 44) java: method request in interface com.pointr.tcp.rpc.P2pRpc cannot be applied to given types;
  required: com.pointr.tcp.rpc.P2pReq<U>,scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag<U>,scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag<V>
  found: com.pointr.tcp.java.sparcle.AppContainerService.ExecuteAppCommandReq
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U,V
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Notice: that the `TypeTag`'s are folded into argument 2 and argument3 of the `request()` method.

```
 reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U,V
       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Here is another "view" of that problem:

[image]

We can see that the java side is expecting the implicit `TypeTag`s as actual *formal parameters* to the method.  Apparently scala does this automatically. . How to get the equivalent on the java side?

I do not know how to make java call into this structure on scala.  Any tips appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037901/how-to-get-the-typetag-for-a-class-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589179/how-to-get-scalas-typetag-and-classtag-in-java.