# How to get the TypeTag for a class in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to call the `functions.typedLit` from Spark library in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026369/adding-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe-with-a-constant-value-of-type-set). And [it asks for two parameters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#typedLit-T-scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag-), a literal object and its type (a `TypeTag`).

The first argument, I can come up with myself (I think). But as for the second one, I don't know how to instantiate an object for it. I'm trying to pass the `TypeTag<Seq<Integer>>` as the second parameter.

Can someone please tell how to create the `TypeTag` for `Seq<Integer>` in **Java**? Here's the code I'm trying to complete:

```
Seq<Integer> seq =  JavaConverters
                      .asScalaIteratorConverter((new ArrayList<Integer>()).iterator())
                      .asScala()
                      .toSeq();
Column litColumn = functions.<Seq<Integer>>typedLit(seq, ???)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your other question I said

> and supplying the CanBuildFrom argument from Java is... technically possible, but not something you want to do.

Unfortunately, for `TypeTag` it's even less possible: unlike `CanBuildFrom`, they aren't supplied by a library, but built into Scala compiler.

The best advice I can give is to create a Scala file supplying the type tags you need to use from Java, since you only should need a limited number of them:

```
object TypeTags {
  val SeqInteger = typeTag[Seq[Integer]]
  ...
  // or 
  val Integer = typeTag[Integer]
  def Seq[A](implicit tt: TypeTag[A]) = typeTag[Seq[A]]
}
```

and then from Java `TypeTags.SeqInteger` or `TypeTags.Seq(TypeTags.Integer)`.

In other places Spark provides special API for use from Java (look for `.java` packages), but I couldn't find one for `functions.typedLit`.

Comment: Thank so much for the answer. But I'm not quite there yet. How should I introduce the `MyTypeTag.scala` to my Java project? Do I need to compile the scala file first? I've hardly ever used Scala and definitely never mixed it with Java. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks, I jsut wanted to say I followed the instructions on this article https://dzone.com/articles/scala-in-java-maven-project and managed to add the scala file to my project. Cheers.