# How to do the Scala's Seq ++ operand in Java

Tags: java, scala

I'm working with Scala's Seq class in Java (`scala.collection.Seq<A>`) and according to [Scala documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html), there a `++` operand that merges two Seq into one. How can I do the same in Java?

Comment: does `seq1.++(seq2)` not work?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh No, it doesn't. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala identifier `++` is translated into `$plus$plus` on JVM. Unfortunately, you can't call `seq1.$plus$plus(seq2)`, because the real signature of `++` is

```
def ++[B >: A, That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

and supplying the `CanBuildFrom` argument from Java is... technically possible, but not something you want to do.

So I suggest converting Scala collections to Java using [`JavaConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) methods before working with them in Java whenever `CanBuildFrom` gets involved.

Comment: Thanks, you seem knowledgeable on Java and Scala. Could you please take a look at my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037901/how-to-get-the-typetag-for-a-class-in-java

Answer (score 0):

To do the same in java, you could use the addAll method. Lets say you have two lists listOne and listTwo.

```
List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<T>(listOne);
resultList.addAll(listTwo);
```